# displaying data based on filter - react todo list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display my todolist based on the filter the user chooses.
at the moment, I have written the code for showing completed only.
but it's not working.

Please take a look and tell why it's not working

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import  './reminderListStyles.css';
import Filters from './Filters';

class ReminderList extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            filter:"completed"
        }
    this.getFilter=this.getFilter.bind(this);   
    }


    getFilter(x){
        this.setState({
            filter:x
        });
        //alert(x);
    }

    render(){



        return(
            <div>
            <ul>
            {this.props.reminder.map((item)=>{

                if(this.state.filter==='show_completed'){
                    if(  item.completed){
                        return  <li key={item.id}
              style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
               onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
               < input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed} />{item.text}</li>
                    }

                }

                return <li key={item.id}
              style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
               onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
               < input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed} />{item.text}</li>

            })}
            </ul>
            <Filters reminders={this.props.reminder}
                        filterState={this.getFilter}
             />
            </div>

            )
    }
}

export default ReminderList;
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working, what is the problem, also the state is set to "completed" and you are comparing with "show_completed". how do you expect it to work correctly

Comment: ah, yes! the initial state is set to completed.
Let me change that.
but the reason I am saying it's not working is that 
it's still displaying completed and not completed both.
even when I click on complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** Instead of `this.state.filter==='show_completed'` it should be `this.state.filter==='completed'`.

**2.** You need to return `null` when `if(item.completed)` condition fails, otherwise it will return the item that you are returning outside of `if` condition.

Write it like this:

```
{this.props.reminder.map((item)=>{

    if(this.state.filter === 'completed'){
        if(item.completed){
           return <li key={item.id}
                      style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
                      onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
                          <input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed} />
                          {item.text}
                  </li>
        }
        return null        //here
    }

    return  <li key={item.id}
              style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
              onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
                  <input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed}/>
                  {item.text}
            </li>

})}
```

**Update:**

Call a function from render method and put the entire map logic inside that:

```
renderTodos(){

    return this.props.reminder.map((item)=>{
        if(this.state.filter === 'completed'){
            if( item.completed){
               return <li key={item.id}
                          style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
                          onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
                              <input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed} />
                              {item.text}
                      </li>
            }
            else null;
        }

        return  <li key={item.id}
                  style={{textDecoration: item.completed? 'line-through':'none'}}
                  onClick = {()=>{this.props.onToggle(item.id)}} >
                      <input type="checkbox" checked={item.completed}/>
                      {item.text}
                </li>

    })}
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.renderTodos()}
            </ul>
            <Filters 
                reminders={this.props.reminder}
                filterState={this.getFilter}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: no, but the values of this.state.filter can be only one of these 3
show_all
show_active
show_completed

Comment: ohk i that case replace `completed` by `show_completed`

Comment: @faraz code that i suggested will filter all the todo's which will be having the status `show_completed`. Just put a `return null` as i suggested it will work correctly.

Comment: ok, it does work now.
and the only thing I added was return null
so, is that okay, or maybe there's still a mistake somewhere?

Comment: another question, which I think is more important is - 
is this the correct way of doing this?
i have seen code where people save the returned value as a variable first and then just put the variable in the html as {returned_value}

what do you say?

Comment: that was the only thing required, reason is when you were not using return null, execution will continue till the last line of the map body, and it was returning the item.

Comment: so, it was still returning all the items, just because I didnt use return null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147650/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-faraz).